Can an outcome variable be used twice in the same model?
When is it appropriate to use the same outcome variable in two likelihoods in the same model framework?
Here is a specific example:
model{
    y ~ bernoulli( (1-psi) * mu);
    y ~ bernoulli( (1-psi) * theta);

    u ~ bernoulli( theta);
}


The only way I have been able to make this model work is by using y in two separate likelihoods. That model formulation recovers simulated parameters perfectly.
Doing this in a joint likelihood (mixture model, log_mix in Stan) results in biased estimates of mu. It only works when the likelihoods are independent.
Update: added R simulation code to show the generative process of the problem:
set.seed(2)
n = 1000
psi = 0.23    # false negative proportion
beta0 = -0.5
X = rnorm(n)
beta = 0.01

y = rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = (1 - psi) * 1/(1+exp(-(beta0 + beta * X))))

# calculate "true" simulated probability of success, taking into account beta * X
# a more thorough way to simulate this would be to first generate y values using only beta0, 
# and then simulating the X values, but I am trying to keep this code block concise.
alpha = mean(1/(1+exp(-(beta0 + beta * X))))


u = rbinom(n, 1, 1/(1+exp(-alpha)))

```


Could you explain in English how you want us to make sense of a random outcome that is simultaneously governed by two different data-generation mechanisms?  What is this code attempting to describe?  Indeed, what are its random variables and what are the parameters?

Sure! y and u = random binary samples from a population with P(success) = theta. mu = regression component, here an intercept for the example. Positive y samples test negative with false negative rate psi. u samples are correct. Psi must be estimated by linking y with true prevalence theta, and must then be used to correctly estimate mu. So y and u are the random variables, while psi, mu and theta are the parameters. Does that help?

I see that you also asked the question on the Stan forum: Is it ok to use the same independent outcome variable twice in a model?.

@dipetkov yes, I had posted it there but then figured that the question wasn't actually that specific to Stan, but rather a general statistical question, so CV seemed like a good place. Hope that's ok and doesn't violate forum policy? I'm pretty new to the forum world.

As I understand the rules, cross-posting -- which is discouraged -- concerns stack exchanges only. I made a note of the link not as a criticism but since it may be interesting to others to read the commentary on the Stan forum.

If you know or are trying to estimate the true prevalence $\theta$, then you do not need a $\mu$ (regression component) - you are working directly with $\theta$.  So, your first line is useless.  If, on the other hand, you don't know the true prevalence $\theta$ but are trying to estimate it using a regression equation - i.e., via estimating $\mu$ - then your second line is redundant.  The point is, it has to be one or the other, as the only way your expressions make sense is if $\theta = \mu$.

The goal is to estimate all parameters. The third line, u, is necessary for getting an unbiased (i.e. no false negatives) sample of the population. This then allows the estimation of psi, by using the second line. And then when psi is estimated, it can be used in the first line for the regression components in mu (intercept and coefficients).  I follow what you say about removing the second line, but only keeping the first line results in wrong estimates of both psi and the regression components. Hence the need to have all 3 lines (or a better solution that allows correct estimation of mu).

See also the link above to the same question, with more information, on the Stan forum. I tried to limit the amount of information in the question to keep things to the point, but that may actually be causing more confusion? Please let me know if more information should be provided.

I am having difficulty seeing how the first block of code correctly models what you are describing in your initial comments.  Moreover, u is superfluous for any question concerning y, so why do you include it?

u is included because it provides the only unbiased information about the success rate theta.  This correct estimate of theta is necessary to inform psi, which is then in turn used to correct for the discrepancy between mu and y.  Excluding any of the equations results in wrong estimates of psi and mu.

Update: this problem has been solved: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/is-it-ok-to-use-the-same-independent-outcome-variable-twice-in-a-model/35312/15.

It remains unclear what the problem actually is.  It sounds like you might have observations of $y$ and $u,$ but that isn't evident, nor is the nature of the sampling known.
